# Write JavaScript Event to Pass to Inherited JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, events

I have a Javascript class `aaa` that asynchronously loads data from our embedded Linux board via CGI.

I have a inherited class `aaa.bbb` that has functions that need to request server data from `aaa`

I currently initiliase both class via

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', aaa.methods.init, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bbb.methods.init, false);
```

What I really want is this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', aaa.methods.init, false);
document.addEventListener('aaa.onServerDataLoaded', bbb.methods.init, false);
```

However, is it possible to write a function in my `aaa` library that when the *first* server data is asynchronously loaded the other library are initialised?

How would `aaa.onServerDataLoaded` look?

```
// The XHR callback
function serverDataCallback(event) {
    if ((event.target.readyState === 4) && (event.target.status === 200)) {
        onServerDataLoad();
    }
};

// The event to bubble up
function onServerDataLoad() {
    // Erm...?! :)
};
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to load the library bbb when the first data is received or is the file containing bbb already loaded and you want to perform initializations on bbb?

Comment: The latter. The `aaa.bbb.js` file  is included in the HTML page.  `aaa` handles all the async server data. `aaa.bbb` requests the client side data through `aaa` at initialization. However, if `aaa` hasn't received the data from the server `aaa.bbb` initialization will fail. Therefore, I want the initialization of `aaa.bbb` to be called when `aaa` gets the server data. I would like to be able to register `aaa.bbb` init function as a listener to `aaa` so that when I develop `aaa.ccc` I can add it's initialisation as well. I don't know how these problems are solved, I've never done this before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have aaa dispatch a custom event.

```
function serverDataCallback(event) {
  if ((event.target.readyState === 4) && (event.target.status === 200)) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("Event"); 
    evt.initEvent("onServerDataLoaded", true, true); 
    document.dispatchEvent(evt); 

  }
};
```

Then you can actually bind one or more event-listeners to this event.

```
document.addEventListener('onServerDataLoaded', function(){
  bbb.init(); 
}, false);
```

Please be aware that this functionality might not be available in all browsers. Most Javascript-Libraries provide similar functionality in some x-browser way.

Have a look at MDN for more in-depth info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/Creating_and_triggering_custom_events

Comment: Perfect.  I've decided to use jQuery for x-browser compatibilty.  What do I need to look at in there?

Comment: Used trigger and bind. `$(document).trigger('serverDataLoaded')` and `$(document).bind('serverDataLoaded', bbb.methods.init)` *Edit*: Sorry I didn't update the page and missed your comment.  Thanks @kioopi!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a javascript library why do you want to check for readyState and status ?
From whatever i understood from your query, you have two Libraries i hope they are Ajax libraries say YUI(aaa.aaa) and jquery(aaa.bbb)
so you can call the jquery initialization methods on response handler of YUI AJAX request

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMContentReady(function(){
//Code to initialize your YUI library (aaa.aaa)
});

YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest("POST", req, {
"success" : function(){

//Call you jquery (aaa.bbb)initialization functions here

}
});
```

I hope this helps you.